# jquery ajax form (jquery.form.js)

Tags: jquery

I would like to use this example http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#html in my page for chat panel.

I have tried exactly this example (just copy+paste from this page), on the page it works, my script works either,  but only once..

I write text, touch the button and see the text bottom, but whenn i change the text and click on the button again, it doesnt work, i have to do refresh the page.

any idea?

Comment: Are you modifying the html with the response?

Answer (score 0):

server code in php file have to keep id="htmlExampleTarget"

```
echo '<div id="htmlExampleTarget" style="background-color:#ffa; padding:20px">' . $_POST['message'] . '</div>';
```